# Problem with data rendering in Flask webpage. One toggle shows the right data while the other doesn't

Tags: python, flask, webpage-screenshot

Here is the link to my project: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ginger-zealous-sunshine

These are the relevant files: comparison.html and main.py

The problem is in the Vehicle Comparison Tool, when the Environmental Effects Data Type is selected. When the Cost Data type is selected, it works as expected, showing the cost-related data and the cost line graph.

[This is what it shows when I select Cost Type Data] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWmWA.png)

This is how it should show for the Environmental Effects Data, just with the other data (electric_environment_data and gas_environment_data in my main.py file), but this is what comes out instead when Environmental Effects Data type is selected:

[This is what it shows when I select Environmental Effetcs Type Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS0YG.png)

No table, a wrong graph, and an empty stacked bar graph. What is the issue? I believe it is with the data rendering, since there are no errors in the console.

I expected the Environmental Effects data to display the table and the graph similarly to the Cost Type Data, but with a stacked bar graph and the electric_environment_data and gas_environment data instead.

Unfortunately it displayed no data, the wrong graph, and an empty bar graph as shown in my screenshot.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)